# Python Folium MarkerCluster Color Customization

Tags: python, folium

I'm creating a leaflet map in folium using MarkerCluster. I have been all over the documentation and searched for examples, but I cannot figure out how to customize the color for a given MarkerCluster or FeatureGroup (e.g., one set in green rather than default blue).

I tried creating the markers individually and iteratively adding them to the MarkerCluster, and that gave me the color I wanted, but then the iFrame html table woudn't function properly, and the popups were not appearing.

The code I've written works flawlessly (an html table used for popups is not supplied), but I'd really like to be able to change the color for one set of markers and retain the popups using the methods in my code. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
or_map = folium.Map(location=OR_COORDINATES, zoom_start=8)

res_popups, res_locations = [], []
com_popups, com_locations = [], []
for idx, row in geo.iterrows():
    if row['Type'] == 'Residential':
        res_locations.append([row['geometry'].y, row['geometry'].x])
        property_type = row['Type']
        property_name = row['Name']
        address = row['address']
        total_units = row['Total Unit']
        iframe = folium.IFrame(table(property_type, property_name, 
                                     address, total_units), width=width, 
                                     height=height)
        res_popups.append(iframe)
    else:
        com_locations.append([row['geometry'].y, row['geometry'].x])
        property_type = row['Type']
        property_name = row['Name']
        address = row['address']
        total_units = row['Total Unit']
        iframe = folium.IFrame(table(property_type, property_name, address, 
                                     total_units), width=width, 
                                     height=height)
        com_popups.append(iframe)


r = folium.FeatureGroup(name='UCPM Residential Properties')
r.add_child(MarkerCluster(locations=res_locations, popups=res_popups))
or_map.add_child(r)

c = folium.FeatureGroup(name='UCPM Commercial Properties')
c.add_child(MarkerCluster(locations=com_locations, popups=com_popups))
or_map.add_child(c)

display(or_map)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just dumping all your locations into the Cluster, you could loop over them and create a Marker for each of them - that way you can set the Marker's color. After creation, you can add the Marker to the desired MarkerCluster.

```
for com_location, com_popup in zip(com_locations, com_popups):
    folium.Marker(com_location,
              popup=com_popup
              icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='info-sign')
              ).add_to(cluster)
```

A different approach would be to modify the style function, as shown [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/MarkerCluster.ipynb) (In[4] and In[5]).

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestion; it all came together when I figured out that the branca IFrame elements had to be passed to Marker as Folium popups: popup = folium.Popup(res_popup)--I had been trying to pass the branca elements directly to the Markers and the popup tables were not displaying.